# How come server is supposed to cache information in REST APIs?

Tags: rest

According to [this](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/) in property 3 and property 4,

> Stateless
>
> Roy fielding got inspiration from HTTP, so it reflects in this
> constraint. Make all client-server interactions stateless. The server
> will not store anything about the latest HTTP request the client made.
> It will treat every request as new. No session, no history.
>
> No client context shall be stored on the server between requests. The
> client is responsible for managing the state of the application.

But then again,

> In REST, caching shall be applied to resources when applicable, and
> then these resources MUST declare themselves cacheable. Caching can be
> implemented on the server or client-side

How is the server being stateless if it can cache information?

Answer (score 5):

tldr: Stateless refers the behavior of a server to not record any information on the client's behalf between calls.

Caches are used as a server optimization strategy for resources that are requested often (and do not change frequently).

---

If a server is "stateless" this mean that no information will be held on the server side on the clients behalf between requests. Thus each request that a client makes must contain all of the required information for the server to perform the desired action. Irrespective of how many calls the client has made on this server previously.

*Stateless* means there is no memory of the past. Every request is performed as if it were being done for the very first time.

*Stateful* means that there is memory of the past. Previous request are remembered and **may** impact behavior of the current Request

Caching is merely holding a copy of a resource that the server is responsible of serving. Caching is commonly used for highly requested resources. Caching strategies can be used by both stateless and stateful services.

In REST when designing an api, you can have Stateless iteration with your clients and you can use caching to store highly requested items in memory to save IO calls to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative reference for REST is Fielding's dissertation.

Fielding's definition of [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) is found in the discussion of network-based architectural styles

> The client-stateless-server style derives from client-server with the additional constraint that no session state is allowed on the server component. Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is kept entirely on the client.

It may help to contrast this idea with [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Differences_from_HTTP), where the server is expected to track session state.

```
RETR example.txt
```

In FTP, to interpret that RETR command correctly, you need to know what the current working directory is for the session, and the clues that tell you that are stored in earlier messages.

Because HTTP requests are self contained, you don't need "sticky" session management.

As Fielding himself notes, [Cookies](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2) violate the stateless rest constraint:

> The same functionality should have been accomplished via anonymous authentication and true client-side state.

Answer (score 0):

**Stateless**, this means that **the server** does not contain any state of the **API client** who is making the call.

**Cacheability** refers to the server's ability to store responses and reuse them for identical future requests.

**So, isn't that a contradiction?**
No, The server can cache information related to a resource but doesn't retain any specific client-related state. For example, it may include a "Last-Modified" header in its response, indicating when the resource was last modified.

---

Here's a simplified sequence of events:

1. **Server Sends Initial Response**: The server responds to a client request with a resource and includes a Last-Modified header.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Type: text/html
   Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT
   [Content of the resource]
   ```
2. **Client Stores Last-Modified Date**: The client stores the Last-Modified date it received.
3. **Subsequent Request**: In a subsequent request, the client includes an If-Modified-Since header with the stored Last-Modified date.

   ```
   GET /resource
   If-Modified-Since: Wed, 01 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT
   ```
4. **Server Checks If Resource Modified**:

   - not modified? then the server can respond with a 304 Not Modified status.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
   ```

   - modified? then the server sends the updated resource along with a new Last-Modified header.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Last-Modified: New-Modified-Date
   [Updated Resource]
   ```

---

Some resources:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-2.2
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag